# Changing eBay API target site from US to UK

Tags: php, xml, ebay-api, ebay-lms

I currently have working project for uploading my products via API to ebay.com (US) website and I am trying to get it to work for eBay's UK website.

What are the parameters I need to change in my API call, besides following.

- `SiteId` : 3 (UK) (in every call)
- `CategorySiteID` : 3
- `X-EBAY-API-SITEID` : 3
- `AddFixedPriceItemRequest->Item->Country` : UK
- `AddFixedPriceItemRequest->Item->Currency` : GBP

I have tried to dump request and response object on each step with `WarningLevel` `High` with no luck of an error message. Every response gives back `success` but products do not show up on website. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please contact the vendor of the API for your support options, on Stackoverflow we normally care about programming questions and that normally involves code, not APIs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem with my configuration on eBay.co.uk site.

Answer (score 3):

Please read below
http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/finding/Concepts/MakingACall.html#StandardURLParameters

Please try and add below parameter (But don't know exactly)

&GLOBAL-ID=EBAY-GB

Answer (score 0):

**X-EBAY-API-SITEID : 3(UK) http://www.ebay.co.uk/. So, you will pass query string siteid=3&**

**EBay Country via side id code. So, Please reffer below link**
http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/shopping/docs/Concepts/ShoppingAPI_FormatOverview.html

**Enumeration Values**
Value   Description
Australia   Australia, site ID 15, abbreviation AU, currency AUD.
Austria Austria, site ID 16, abbreviation AT, currency EUR.
Belgium_Dutch   Belgium (Dutch), site ID 123, abbreviation BENL, currency EUR.
Belgium_French  Belgium (French), site ID 23, abbreviation BEFR, currency EUR.
Canada  Canada, site ID 2, abbreviation CA, currencies CAD and USD.
CanadaFrench    CanadaFrench, site ID 210, abbreviation CAFR, currencies CAD and USD.
China   China, site ID 223, abbreviation CN, currency CNY.
CustomCode  Placeholder value. See token.
eBayMotors  eBay Motors, site ID 100, currency USD.
France  France, site ID 71, abbreviation FR, currency EUR.
Germany Germany, site ID 77, abbreviation DE, currency EUR.
HongKong    Hong Kong, site ID 201, abbreviation HK, currency HKD.
India   India, site ID 203, abbreviation IN, currency INR.
Ireland Ireland, site ID 205, abbreviation IE, currency EUR.
Italy   Italy, site ID 101, abbreviation IT, currency EUR.
Malaysia    Malaysia, site ID 207, abbreviation MY, currency MYR.
Netherlands Netherlands, site ID 146, abbreviation NL, currency EUR.
Philippines Philippines, site ID 211, abbreviation PH, currency PHP.
Poland  Poland, site ID 212, abbreviation PL, currency PLN.
Russia  Russia, site ID 215, abbreviation RU, currency RUB.
Singapore   Singapore, site ID 216, abbreviation SG, currency SGD.
Spain   Spain, site ID 186, abbreviation ES, currency EUR.
Sweden  Sweden, site ID 218, abbreviation SE, currency SEK.
Switzerland Switzerland, site ID 193, abbreviation CH, currency CHF.
Taiwan  Taiwan, site ID 196, abbreviation TW, currency TWD.
UK  United Kingdom, site ID 3, abbreviation UK, currency GBP.
US  USA, site ID 0, abbreviation US, currency USD.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the HTTP Headers

```
X-EBAY-C-MARKETPLACE-ID:EBAY_GB
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).